# Detect drop target node in a sencha ext-gwt 3.0 tree

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Context: sencha ext-gwt **3.0** (beta3). I am using dnd to let the user re-arrange a tree, one element at a time. I can easily get the dragged element but didn't find how to get the drop target. Here is my code:

```
final TreeDropTarget<IMyModel> target = new TreeDropTarget<IMyModel>(mytree);
target.setAllowSelfAsSource(true);
target.setAllowDropOnLeaf(true);
target.setFeedback(DND.Feedback.BOTH);
target.addDropHandler(new DndDropEvent.DndDropHandler()
{
  @Override
  public void onDrop(final DndDropEvent event)
  {
    IMyModel dragged = mytree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    // TODO get the drop target element!
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
target.addDropHandler(new DndDropHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDrop(DndDropEvent event) {
        final TreeNode<MyModel> item = source.getWidget().findNode(event.getDragEndEvent().getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().<Element> cast());
        MyModel newParent = item.getModel();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the GXT 3.0 beta examples available [here](http://www.sencha.com/examples-dev/#ExamplePlace%3areorderingtree)

Comment: In the example they do not show how to detect the drop target, do they?

Comment: it has drag and drop but doesn't show how to detect the drop target node from what I see. Can you propose some code?